# weird issue when creating a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having an issue with creating a dictionary. The dictionary is basically {booknumbers: list-of-2-tuples}. Here, pairs is also a 2-tuple, and the path is a list.

```
def pairs2dict(pairs, paths):
    dic = {}
    for pair in pairs:
        booknumber = getbooknumber(pair)
        path = getpath(pair)
        if booknumber in dic:
            dic[booknumber].append([pair[1], paths[booknumber])
        else:
            dic[booknumber] = [pair[1], paths[booknumber])

    return dic
```

This gives me a dic which is all fine and good, except for the first 2-tuple under each book number is split up, and are two separate elements.

The following bit fixes the problem, but I have no idea why I'm having the issue in the first place. Thanks for any info!

```
for booknumber in dic:
    dic[booknumber][0] = [dic[booknumber][0], dic[booknumber][1]]
    dic[booknumber].pop(1)
```

Comment: Please show a sample of the input, the unexpected output, and what it should look like.

Comment: Can you provide the actual output of the function and the desired output.

Comment: you want `dic[booknumber] = [(pair[1], paths[booknumber])]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily solve your problem by getting rid of the conditional by using a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def pairs2dict(pairs, paths):
    dic = defaultdict(list)
    for pair in pairs:
        booknumber = getbooknumber(pair)
        path = getpath(pair)
        dic[booknumber].append([pair[1], paths[booknumber])
    return dic
```

Answer (score 0):

In the if statement you are appending a list to a list, but in the else statement you are appending raw data to the list. You need to wrap the initial data into a list beforehand.

```
    if booknumber in dic:
        dic[booknumber].append([pair[1], paths[booknumber])
    else:
        dic[booknumber] = [[pair[1], paths[booknumber]]]
```